# Replace box-shadow

Tags: html, css, replace, properties, box-shadow

I've got 2 .css files in my page in this order

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calib.css">
```

In main.css I've got

```
input[type="button"]{
  box-shadow: 0 0px 10px blue;
}
```

and in calib.css I've got

```
.btn-active{
  box-shadow: 0 0px 10px red;
}
```

In the HTML I put this elements

```
<input type="button" class="btn-active" value="Button 1">
<input type="button" class="" value="Button 2">
```

But the color of the box-shadow in the Button 1 remains blue.

Is there a way to replace a CSS property value without creating a new class with the input[type="button"] content?

Thanks!

Comment: You want to go into `!important` hell. Also the `style` is overwritten, when you use the same `selector` in file.

Comment: Try using `input.btn-active`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use `!important`. use `input.btn-active` instead

```css
input[type="button"]{
  box-shadow: 0 0px 10px blue;
}
input.btn-active{
  box-shadow: 0 0px 10px red;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="btn-active" value="Button 1">
<input type="button" class="" value="Button 2">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> .btn-active{
  box-shadow: 0 0px 10px red !important;
}
```

or

```
input.btn-active{
  box-shadow: 0 0px 10px red;
}
```

Comment: I discovered the second way 5 minutes ago, using `input[type="button"].btn-active` to be complete.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be more specific specifying your selectors.

You could use `input.btn-active` and keep the order of the way you specify the css the same.

```css
input[type="button"] {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px blue;
}

input.btn-active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="button" class="btn-active" value="Button 1">
  <input type="button" class="" value="Button 2">
</form>
```

If you want to be more specific use `input[type="button"].btn-active`. That way specifying it like this would also work:

```css
input[type="button"].btn-active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px red;
}

input[type="button"] {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px blue;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="button" class="btn-active" value="Button 1">
  <input type="button" class="" value="Button 2">
</form>
```